Why typescript can't inference the value of Record could be undefined?
example:
var foo: Record<string, string> = { a: 'a' };
var value = foo['b']; // value of Record could be undefined

Why typescript can't infer this case, to protect the undefined usage.
I hope vscode ts extension can make some warning to this case

TypeScript can't infer this because the Record<string, string> type assumes all keys exist.

Why did you explicitly specify the type? There is the expected error without specifying the type as Record<string, string>.

Using noUncheckedIndexedAccess in your tsconfig should get you this behaviour. It's very annoying though.
